# What is the bar that rounds my hp, which looks like a countdown?

Tags: mdk

Every level I play, the bar that rounds my HP, drains itself.

But after finishing the game, I see that it doesn't represent an important objective or goal... Is there a time limit, or do I achieve a bonus from that (a secret feature maybe)? Maybe an unfinished "thing" that the developers left?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the the number of innocent people left that the mine crawler hasn't killed yet.

From the [manual](http://cdn4.steampowered.com/Manuals/38450/Manual%20English.pdf?t=1255985825) on page 7:

> Q: I keep seeing these random messages on the screen, like "Au Revoir,
> Paris". What do they mean?
>
> A: If you look at the meter in the lower
> right corner of the screen, there is a green band surrounding it. At
> its fullest, it indicates the number of people alive near the
> city-mine crawler. As the bar decreases in size, that indicates that
> more and more innocent people are dying. When the bar is depleted, a
> major city has been destroyed by an alien city because you took so
> long. Way to go..

The manual is unclear as to what, if any, effect this has on gameplay.